# MFC control unique identifier at runtime

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, controls

I had a CDialog with the same group of controls repeated 10 times. There was a lot of logic so I refactored the dialog to have just a 1 CDialog but repeated 10 times.

So instead of having 10 edit box with IDs:

```
    IDD_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 680, 347
    STYLE DS_SETFONT | WS_CHILD
    FONT 10, "Segoe UI", 0, 0, 0x1
    BEGIN
        EDITTEXT    IDC_EDT_NAME1,34,226,80,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL|ES_READONLY
        ...
        EDITTEXT    IDC_EDT_NAME10,34,226,80,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL|ES_READONLY
    END
```

Now I have this:

```
    IDD_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 680, 347
    STYLE DS_SETFONT | WS_CHILD
    FONT 10, "Segoe UI", 0, 0, 0x1
    BEGIN
        EDITTEXT    IDC_EDT_NAME,34,226,80,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL|ES_READONLY
    END
```

But I copy it 10 times in the screen. So far so good...my problem now is that I need to identify controls in the screen to use a automation testing tool and the control ID is always the same for all 10 edit boxes. Is there any property in the control I can use to uniquely identify controls apart from the Control ID???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a child dialog that is numbered individually and than place the control in the child dialog. Use WS_CHILD for it.

With this trick, you can determine the parent of the child too.

In code project you find a sample and requirements how to embed a child dialog in your dialog.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4408/Creating-embedded-dialogs-in-MFC

Another way is just to set new Ids after the controls are created.
CWnd::SetDlgCtrlID will do this. YOu can keep them unique on this way

Comment: My problem is not how to embed the dialogs...this is already implemented and working....I need to identify every control in these embedded dialogs individually. Testing team is using a tool that identify all controls by using the ControlID and now all this id's are duplicated.

Comment: Changed my answer